# Greatest greatest common divisor

Tags: code-golf, number-theory

Find the greatest gcd of the numbers \$n^m + k\$ and \$(n+1)^m + k\$ for given `m` and `k`.

For example, for `m=3, k=1` we have:

- \$n = 1\$: \$\gcd(1^3 + 1, 2^3 + 1) = 1\$
- \$n = 2\$: \$\gcd(2^3 + 1, 3^3 + 1) = 1\$

\$\vdots\$

- \$n = 5\$: \$\gcd(5^3 + 1, 6^3 + 1) = 7\$ (max)

\$\vdots\$

- \$n \to \infty\$

#### Input/Output

Input is L lines through file or stdin, EOF terminated. Each line contains two integers: `m` and `k` separated by a space.

Output is L integers separated by *any pattern* of whitespace characters (tabs, spaces, newlines etc).

#### Examples

**Input**

```
2 4
2 7
3 1
4 1
3 2
5 4
10 5
```

**Output**

```
17
29
7
17
109
810001
3282561
```

#### Update

I can't find a proof that the solution is bounded for all `n` given some `m` and `k`, so you only have to find the GGCD for \$n < 10,000,000\$.

Comment: For m=5, k=4 value is >= 810001.

Comment: @Ante: Interesting! Are you sure? Do you know for what `n` is 810001?

Comment: n=329529. Are you sure that max(gcd(n,n+1) of series) is good defined? I can't find a proof or good rezone for that, except very much regularity in gcd(n,n+1) series.

Comment: Please clarify spec: how is n arrived at?

Comment: @mckenzie: brute force, iterating n to few millions and checking gcd().

Comment: Is `n` an integer? Is `n >= 0`?

Comment: @trinithis: gcd is *by definition* about non-zero integers, unless specified otherwise. Also, there is no point in taking `n < 0` but feel free to do so if that shortens your code.

Answer (score 6):

Update:

GGCD for given `m` and `k` is good [defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56120/number-of-solutions-for-pair-of-discrete-logarithm-like-equations).

This is table of GGCD tested for n up to 500000.

```
m/k      1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10
2        5       9      13      17      21      25      29      33      37      41
3        7     109      61     433     169     973     331    1729     547    2701
4       17      33      49      65      81      97     113     129     145    2093
5      341   52501  258751  810001       1  131371       1       1  501311 2846591
6       65     129     193     257   21507     385     449   22059     577     641
7     3683  235747       1       1      71  438299  940507   33461     757  110503
8     4369     513     769   13325    1281  149089  202609    2049  975937  617201
9   359233  232537  202927  470983  123019  708589  241117 5601589  398581   19783
10   62525  514299  183757  807517 1094187 16856405  97477    8193  377897 25919971
```

For `m==2 or 4` it looks quite good :-)

It seems that if **p_i<sup>n_i</sup>** is gcd for some **n**, where **p_i** is a prime, than every combination of products of **p_i**'s with exponents **<= n_i** is also gcd for some **n**. E.g. for m=8,k=2, 3^3 and 19 are gcd of type **p_i<sup>n_i</sup>**, also 57, 171 and 513 are gcd's.

Some theory background: If `g = gcd(n) > 1` for some `n`, and `d > 1` and `d divide g` (it can be `d=g`) than `d divide gcd(n±d)`. It is easy to prove. That means:

- If you find some `g = gcd(n) > 1` for some `n`, than `gcd(n±d) > 1`. So, it is enough to jump for found prime number of steps while iterating `n`.
- If prime `p` divide some `gcd()` than there is `n <= p` where `p` divide `gcd(n)`. Prime `p` will 'appear' in `gcd(n)` for some `n <= p`.

These properties can speed up search, but still there is a question is GGCD good defined.

Comment: Except m=4,k=10 - that one is very interesting and breaks the pattern (2093).  Makes one wonder if you made `n` go higher you might find even higher numbers for m=4, k<10.

Comment: And m=7, k=9 has GGCD of at least 9846271 (see n=9790012).

Comment: @mellamokb: maybe it doesn't break a pattern, 161 is gcd() for n = 241. For m=4,k=10 there is no other gcd till n=10^7.

Comment: @Howard: Now I checked also till n=10^7:-) Since 757 and 9846271 are both prime, than 757*9846271=7453627147 is also gcd() for some large n.

Comment: @Ante: I was commenting about the fact that your table above has 2093 as the entry for m=4, k=10... or am I misreading the table??

Comment: @mellamokb: it has 2093, which is GGCD for n<=500000. 161 is smaller gcd, which should be expected extension of GGCDs for k<10, which are k*16+1.

Comment: @Ante: Gotcha, we're on the same page now.  I was meaning a pattern on GGCD, not patterns on possible gcd's that appear in the list.  So it's quite possible for an n>500000, perhaps there's a higher gcd for, say, m=4, k=3, which was my point.  No way to know unless the theory behind the patterns can be made more thorough and conclusive I guess :)

Comment: @Ante yes of course (it is for n=6400019891).

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby - <strike>84</strike> <strike>81</strike> <strike>80</strike> 79 chars

Passes all test cases, not sure if it can handle larger numbers.

```
$<.map{|l|m,k=l.split.map &:to_i;p (1..$$).map{|n|(n**m+k).gcd (n+1)**m+k}.max}
```

#### Test

```
D:\tmp>ruby cg_gcd.rb < cg_gcd.in
17
29
7
17
109
3361
```

Comment: What happens if `$$` becomes small? You cannot guarantee any value for it.

Answer (score 1):

**Sage, 92**

```
for l in sys.stdin.readlines():m,k=l.split();print max(gcd(n^m+k,(n+1)^m+k)for n in[1..1e7])
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
*@Ɱȷ7+gƝṀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/L4dHGdSe2m2unH5v7cGfD/8PL9R81rfn/P5qLM9pIR8EkVgfCMAczjHUUDMEMExgDKGIEZpjCFBsa6CiYAlmxAA)

This times out on TIO no matter the input due to the `Ɱȷ7` which iterates over the range \$1, 2, ..., 10^7\$. By reducing the `7` to a smaller value, we can get TIO to actually output some results (obviously it gets it wrong for inputs where \$n > 10^5\$): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/L4dHGdSe2m2qnH5v7cGfD/8PL9R81rfn/P5qLM9pIR8EkVgfCMAczjHUUDMEMExgDKGIEZMQCAA)

Not exactly spec-conforming, but given the age I didn't see much issue with that. Takes input in the form of command line arguments. \$m\$ first, then \$k\$

### How it works

```
*@Ɱȷ7+gƝṀ - Main link. Takes m as a left argument and k on the right
   ȷ7     - 10000000
  Ɱ       - Over each n between 1 and 10000000:
*@        -   Calculate n^m
     +    -   Add k
       Ɲ  - Over each neighbouring pair in the list (i.e. n^m+k and (n+1)^m+k):
      g   -   Calculate their GCD
        Ṁ - Output the maximum
```